# Spatial contiguity: Coding Queen Contiguity for a dummy variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, spatial

I have spatial time-series data with grids as basic units. I now need to create a yearly measure for the occurrence of an event (represented by a dummy) in contiguous grids.

For example, here, by the rules of queen contiguity, the value would be 1/8=0,125.

0 0 1
0 x 0
0 0 0

I have ID variables, coordinates, and the row- and column number of each grid in the data, but I am at a loss how I could calculate my measure.

Comment: To be honest, I have found very little information on the issue around, and thus, don't even have a starting point. I have tried doing this with GeoDa, however, the spatial weight matrix that you can create for queen contiguity is simply contiguity- based- and doesn't allow to be contingent on the values of variables in the neighbouring grids.
Secondly, I have tried to create spatial weight matrices in Stata using several plugins, but the results would exceed Statas' maximum matsizes of 11000. Hence, I switched to R to create a variable capturing spatial lag and resort to using that in Stata.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you wrote some code to simulate the kind of data that you are working with. Are the data very sparse (very few events compared to grid size)? Also, do you need to calculate the contiguity for every single point in the grid, or just a few points?

Comment: The data is based on the PRIO Grid dataset and entails sub-Sahara Africa (see http://file.prio.no/ReplicationData/PRIO-GRID/PRIO-GRID_codebook_v1_01.pdf). For every Polygon, there are 20 years in the data, totalling roughly 130000 observations (i.e. 6500 grids). I am interested in relatively restricted occurences of conflict. I do not care about the contiguity of every single point in the grid, only in the directly contiguous grids, as shown in the example above (the x is my observation of interest, and the "spatial lag" variable for it has to be calculated for every yearly grid in the data).

Comment: Isn't the spatial lag already included in the PRIO-GRID dataset as 'conflag1'? Although this lag only includes contiguous cells within the same country. Otherwise maybe [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89812/calculating-spatial-lags-per-year-in-r/92468) might provide some guidance.

Comment: Thanks for this- the second part looks extremely helpful. The PRIO-GRID dataset includes a conflag-variable (even of higher orders), but that doesn't help me, since I coded my own, spatially more restricted indicator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with raster data, you can calculate focal statistics with the `raster` package.

For example:

```
library(raster)

# Create fake binary data
r <- raster(matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), 10))

# Focal mean of the (binary) values of the 8-cell (fewer at grid's edges)
#  neighbourhood of each cell.
r_focal <- focal(r, matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 3), mean, 
                 pad=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

The input and output look like this:

```
plot(stack(r, r_focal), axes=FALSE, main='')
```

[image]

See `?focal` for more details.